# how to find liked posts with user id

Tags: node.js

i am developing project using nodejs. I want to check if the user's userId is the same as the user of the post like. How should I be able to check ?

```js
 const audio = await Audio.find({likes: userId})
```

This is the post data i want to find

```js
{
    "title": "Điêu Toa",
    "music": "public/audio/music_6149812c44cf4d33f410d680_1633941621172.mp3",
    "singer": "Massew x Pháo",
    "size": "2.72mb",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-10-11T08:37:42.840Z"
    },
    "owner": "6149812c44cf4d33f410d680",
    "description": "Lời nói cứ như là bạc là vàng có ta và chàng ngồi ở đây chứng dám cho, chẳng việc gì phải lắng lo ~~",
    "category": "Electronic",
    "__v": 48,
    "likes": [{
        "user": "616c09216e4b2ff62f550c39"
    }, {
        "user": "6149812c44cf4d33f410d680"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that

```
 const audio = await Audio.find({likes: {$elemMatch: {user: userId}}})
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful for me !

Comment: It would be great if you upvote my answer if it was helpful :)